# 'Route' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RouteAttribute'

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, routes

I am using Attribute routing. I need both the assemblies reference. I've tried, but not worked for me. Does anyone know how to fix this? Here is my Controller code:
Namespaces

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Task1CRUD.Repository;
using Task1CRUD.Model;

namespace Task1CRUD.Controllers
{

    [Route("api/[Controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CustomerController:Controller
    {
            private readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRep;
            public CustomerController(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
            {
                _customerRep = customerRepository;
            }

            // GET api/values
            [HttpGet("")]
            public async Task<List<Customer>> GetCustomers()
            {
                return await _customerRep.GetCustomers();
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: It's pretty confusing that there is the same class in the same package under two different namespaces. I lost several hours trying to figure out why my Controller was not being found only to realize the wrong namespace has been used, because included automatically by IntelliSense.

Answer (score 1):

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;

Just Comment out that namespace and all will be will. Please refer to:

In this case, you need to specify whether you want to use the **RouteAttribute** from the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components** namespace or the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc** namespace, depending on the context of your code.

For example, if you are working in a **Blazor application** (client-side or server-side), you would typically use the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute**. Here's how you can specify it

If you are working on an **ASP.NET Core MVC controller**, you would typically use the **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RouteAttribute.**

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the full class name directly on the RouteAttribute like this:

```
[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Route("api/[Controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CustomerController:Controller
{
        private readonly ICustomerRepository _customerRep;
        public CustomerController(ICustomerRepository customerRepository)
        {
            _customerRep = customerRepository;
        }

        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet("")]
        public async Task<List<Customer>> GetCustomers()
        {
            return await _customerRep.GetCustomers();
        }

}
```

Comment: I know about how to alias a namespace. Which is the 'one' to use now for AspNet Core 5.0 in 2021? The choices are 'System.Web.Http.Route', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Route' or 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Route'?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `using RouteAttribute = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RouteAttribute;` if you need to use attribute from `AspNetCore.Mvc` or `using RouteAttribute = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RouteAttribute;` - if from `AspNetCore.Components`.

I'd recomend you to download ReSharper.